# Use .Value of Object in a `For` Loop, when referring to closed Workbook array, without opening the Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I checked similar questions, but none of them seemed to provide a solution.

I need the `.Values` from Workbook `MIDI`, WorkSheet `DL`, `.Cells` from A3 to LastRow to WorkSheet `HDaER` in the current WorkBook, `.Cells` A2 to Last Row.

I use this `For` Loop to refer to an array in the current WorkBook, that contains the sheet `HDaER`.

When I try to use the same approach to refer to a closed WorkBook (`MIDI`), Worksheet `DL`, I get nothing as `.Values` in `HDaER`.

```vb
    Dim MIDI As Workbook
    Dim DL As Worksheet
    Dim HDaER As Worksheet
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim n As Long
    Dim o As Long
    Set HDaER = Sheets("HistoricalDataandExcessReturns")
    
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Insert dates
    
    strFile = "C:\Users\Betty\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\B4D9BCD10BE9B5248AFCB2BE2411BA10\MQL4\Files\MultiInstrDataInput.xlsm"
    Set MIDI = Workbooks.Open(strFile, True, True)
    Set DL = Workbooks("MultiInstrDataInput.xlsm").Sheets("DataList")
                               
    For n = 3 To DL.Range("$B" & DL.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If DL.Range("$A" & n).Value <> "" Then
            o = HDaER.Cells(HDaER.Rows.Count, "$A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            HDaER.Range("$A" & o).Value = DL.Cells(n, 1).Value
        End If
    Next n
                
    MIDI.Close False
            
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
        
End Sub
```

No errors are displayed, but no `.Values` are moved.
I prefer to use a `For` Loop, instead of `.Copy`.

Comment: You cannot do this with a closed workbook - why not open it?

Comment: @Tim Williams: The closed WorkBook `MIDI` serves as a DataBase, contains a lot of information and is quite heavy. However I would consider this as an option, by removing the `MIDI.Close False` Line. Do you think that will work?

Comment: @TimWilliams: Still nothing. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Not seeing any obvious problems in your code - have you tried debugging?

Comment: @TimWilliams: Ran it trough the debugger and the result is the same. Please have in mind that there is no error displayed for the whole code.

Comment: Try using [Option Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/option-explicit-statement) at the start of the module. The `HDaER` variable is never declared (instead an unused variable called `HistoricalDataandExcessReturns` is declared).

Comment: did your code hit this line? `HDaER.Range("$A" & o).Value = DL.Cells(n, 1).Value`

Comment: @barrowc: Will try it now.

Comment: @barrowc: Tried. Not working. Good call, though. Edited the post.

Comment: @TimWilliams: It always hits that line, but nothing is derived from the closed WorkBook.

Comment: What closed workbook?  Aren't you opening the workbook before the loop?  Are you using any error handling?

Comment: @TimWilliams: I am not using any Error Handling. You asked why not just keep it open and I got rid of the line that was closing it. I am opening the workbook before the loop. Still didn't work, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only suggest a few minor tweaks, but I'm not seeing any problems with your existing code.  If values exist but are not getting copied then there's some pice of information missing.

```
Sub Tester()

    'use contrants for fixed values
    Const STR_FILE As String = "C:\Users\Betty\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\" & _
                   "B4D9BCD10BE9B5248AFCB2BE2411BA10\MQL4\Files\MultiInstrDataInput.xlsm"

    Dim MIDI As Workbook, DL As Worksheet, HDaER As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long, o As Long, v

    Set HDaER = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HistoricalDataandExcessReturns") ' if in same file as the code
    o = HDaER.Cells(HDaER.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'start row for copied values

    Set MIDI = Workbooks.Open(STR_FILE, True, True)
    Set DL = MIDI.Sheets("DataList")

    For n = 3 To DL.Cells(DL.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        v = DL.Cells(n, "A").Value
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print "copying value '" & v & "' to A" & o
            HDaER.Cells(o, "A").Value = v
            o = o + 1
        End If
    Next n

    MIDI.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: Much appreciation! Thank you!